# Git Extensions not showing all files to commit at once

Tags: git

I'm Using Git Extensions GUI for GIT on Windows.

With a new project with some hundred files, not all new files are shown for a commit,
I have to to multiple Commits to get all the files.. is there somewhere a option, a limit
to set this behaviour? (yes, I know .gitignore, the files are not ignored, but only shown in
chunks of ca. 20 files)

It's Git Extensions 1.92 with Git 1.6.5.1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't show up in the [Git Extension TODO list](http://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/blob/master/TODO.txt) (Visual Studio Git Extension).
Or in the [issue page](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues) (for the Windows Explorer Git Extension)

If there is such a limit, revert to the shell: if a `git status` displays the right files to be committed, a '`git commit -A -m "..."`' will commit *every* files for sure, not just the first 200.

Answer (score 0):

I never have had this problem; I sometimes stage over ten thousand files at once. This sounds like a bug. Please report it on the [Git Extensions issue tracker](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues).

A possible workaround for now: use the "add files" button in the commit dialog and enter '.' (dot) in the file pattern box. You could also try "stage all" in the commit dialog instead of selecting all files and stage the selected files.

Also, try updating to the latest version, version 2.09.